# My solidity function returns a transaction hash and not a uint

Tags: javascript, solidity

My function keeps returning a transaction hash but it is supposed to return a uint. I call it as a function in the console sale.priceOfEther(). im using solidity 0.5.0 and ganache.

```
    function priceOfEther() public view returns (uint256){
    uint256 maxTokenPrice = WEI_DECIMALS.div(100).mul(7); //max price $0.07 USD per token multiplied by wei early to avoid truncation by division.
    uint256 minTokenPrice = WEI_DECIMALS.div(1000).mul(7); //min price $0.007 USD per token multiplied by wei early to avoid truncation by division.
    uint256 minWeiPerToken = minTokenPrice.div(ethUSD);
    uint256 maxWeiPerToken = maxTokenPrice.div(ethUSD);
    uint256 increments = (maxWeiPerToken.sub(minWeiPerToken)).div(AVG_NUM_INVESTORS); 
    price = minWeiPerToken.add(increments.mul(count));
    if (price > maxWeiPerToken) {
        price = maxWeiPerToken;
    }
    assert(price != 0);        
    return price;
}
```

this is what is returned in the truffle console

```
{ tx: '0x8c3c2b4979117f380a7f6d39fd6f46e3566436ada25b5048ecaaef40743f5586',
  receipt: 
   { transactionHash: '0x8c3c2b4979117f380a7f6d39fd6f46e3566436ada25b5048ecaaef40743f5586',
     transactionIndex: 0,
     blockHash: '0xc3410bdede3bb7afe8889065dc8089a48d7e1285c63e7c43a205bd33d7cc0884',
     blockNumber: 11,
     from: '0x3f32e6ca9e7f433d0f5dea6b1024d3b0768e2dbf',
     to: '0x6bab62d945dfe3c862caf9a3b59c6c435f3de1d4',
     gasUsed: 50007,
     cumulativeGasUsed: 50007,
     contractAddress: null,
     logs: [],
     status: true,
     logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
     rawLogs: [] },
  logs: [] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the solidity function to

```
public view returns uint
```

Comment: If you want to add info or otherwise improve an existing answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/63931934/7733418 ) please edit the existing one, instead of adding another (very short) answer. Otherwise you risk that less observant users give you negative feedback for the impression of you just reusing the solution core of another answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The Community Bot definitly is one of the less observant users....

Answer (score -1):

If the function is view it must return the integer, try pure modifier or use string.

Comment: Please be more precise, add example code. See [How To Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Are you aware that you can [edit] this answer post for the purpose of adding info, code, explanations, or for otherwise improving it according to [answer]?